# bootstrap 5 carousel controls doesn't work and indicators doesn't show

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a simple bootstrap carousel on my html, but the controls does not seem to work, and the indicators not appearing.

**edit:**
I have looked into the documentation and did what they said there but it did not work.

the code looks like so:

```css
.gallery-carousel
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 8vh;
        height: 60vh;
        width: 90%;
        left: 5%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .carousel-inner,
    .carousel-item
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-item img
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!--Carousel-->
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide gallery-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" style="background-image: url('https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4528/38249721602_1dfb84e8a9_b.jpg')">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" style="background-image: url('https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4524/37570788654_c315f9d0b0_b.jpg')">
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
</div>
```

I have looked for other answers on here but none worked for me.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Comment: @Coja Unfortunately no.

Comment: Post js, and i think someone will help you then,i think that functions run on js, not CSS nor HTML, as i know very little js :(

Comment: @Coja I have no js, from my understanding and the documentation bootstrap carousel does not need js in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have managed to make it work by adding an event listener manualy like so:

```
    $(".carousel-control-prev").click(function () {
    $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel('prev');
})
$(".carousel-control-next").click(function () {
    $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel('next');
})
```

Although the indicators are not showing and causing errors, when I remove them everything works.